# Expression with Math.random() always returns the same value

Tags: java, casting

For some reason this line of code `int u=(int)Math.random()*6 + 1;` will only return a 1 as a result.

I found out that its just skipping the whole `(int)Math.random()*6` and is only using the 1 as when I changed it to 2 it only returned 2.

Anyone know What's happening?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The cast of `Math.random()` to `int` is occurring before the multiplication by 6.  The cast operator is of [higher precedence](https://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/11precedence/) than `*`.

The `Math.random()` method returns a random number between `0` (inclusive) and `1` (exclusive), so the cast always returns `0`.

To provide the proper range, multiply `Math.random()` *before* the cast by inserting parentheses.  The range of `Math.random() * 6` is `0` (inclusive) to `6` (exclusive).

```
int u = (int) (Math.random()*6) + 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

What is happening:

1. `Math.random()`Returns a double value with a positive sign, greater than or equal to 0.0 and less than 1.0.
2. `(int)Math.random()` cost the double value to `0`, since type cast has a higher priority compared with `*`.
3. `(int)Math.random()*6` always is `0`,you get what you have.